# When should I use "phantasy" rather than "fantasy"?

Tags: difference, spelling

I am a native speaker of Italian, and since the equivalent word in Italian is *fantasia*, I write *fantasy*.
A friend of mine told me that *phantasy* is also an English word. Considering that generally, when in Italian a word uses an *f* followed by an *a*, the equivalent English word uses *pha*, I am confused about the correct spelling.

What is the correct spelling between *phantasy*, and *fantasy*? Is it correct to say that *phantasy* is an English word currently used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely *Fantasy*.

*Phantasy* is an archaic spelling, currently used for stylistic purposes.

Comment: It should be noted that in the context of psychology, "phantasy" is used as a technical term to refer to subconscious or unconscious imaginings, as distinct from just daydreaming. "Fantasy" is almost universally used everywhere else.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantasy_Star_Online) is literally the *only* place I have ever seen “phantasy.”

Answer (score 3):

Oxford English Dictionary seems to think either can be used:

> fantasy | phantasy, n.
>
> Etymology:  < Old French fantasie (French fantaisie), (= Provencal fantazia, Spanish, Portuguese fantasía, Italian fantasia), < Latin phantasia, < Greek ϕαντασία lit. ‘a making visible’, < ϕαντάζειν to make visible, < ϕαίνειν to show.

In use:

> 1858   R. A. Vaughan Ess. & Remains I. 6   Not a phantasy in religion..but might there soar or flutter.
>
> 1876   ‘G. Eliot’ Daniel Deronda III. vi. xlviii. 379   Fantasies moved within her like ghosts.